# Custom Cursor Smooth Transition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I would be really happy if someone can help me!

I'm facing an issue that I've been trying to resolve but haven't found a satisfactory solution yet. I'm seeking assistance from someone more knowledgeable.

My objective is to use a custom cursor that is simply a 20px by 20px black dot. I have attempted two approaches so far:

Initially, I tried using an element to represent the custom cursor and control its behavior. This method has worked for me in the past, but I'm currently working with a draggable Swiper slider. Unfortunately, when dragging, the custom cursor jumps to the previous slide.

As an alternative, I attempted to use the 'cursor: url("image")' CSS property. While this approach technically works, it lacks the option to scale the cursor. To work around this limitation, I change the image on hover to a larger dot. However, this transition is not smooth at all.

If anyone could offer their assistance and guidance, I would be immensely grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions:

One option is to use the **CSS cursor property** with a **url()** value that points to an image file of your custom cursor. You can also specify the coordinates of the cursor's hotspot, which is the point within the cursor that is being pointed to. For example:

```css
.custom-cursor {
  cursor: url("black-dot.png") 10 10, auto;
}
```

This will apply a custom cursor with a black dot image and a hotspot at (10, 10) pixels. The **auto** keyword is a fallback value in case the image fails to load.

Another option is to use **JavaScript** to create a custom cursor element and attach it to the mouse movement event. You can also use JavaScript to hide the default cursor by setting its style to **none**. For example:

```js
// Get the custom cursor element
let cursor = document.getElementById('custom-cursor');

// Attach a mousemove event listener to the document
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  // Update the custom cursor position
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX - cursor.clientWidth / 2 + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY - cursor.clientHeight / 2 + 'px';
});
// Disable dragging to prevent the not-allowed cursor 
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
// Scaling
document.querySelectorAll('.big-cursor').forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    cursor.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
  });
  ele.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget && !e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('big-cursor')) {
      cursor.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Hide the default cursor */

html {
  cursor: none;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

#custom-cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='20' width='20'%3E%3Ccircle cx='10' cy='10' r='7' stroke='%2300000077' stroke-width='3' fill='%23000000' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="square big-cursor">This div has big cursor</div>
<div class="square">This div has normal cursor</div>
<div id="custom-cursor"></div>
```

This will create a custom cursor element with a black dot and move it along with the mouse position. The **pointer-events: none** property prevents the custom cursor from interfering with other elements.

I hope this helps you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing these Russell!

The problem with this solution is that the cursor jumps when I drag between slides: https://stephen-akehurst.webflow.io/.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).